# Formatting DataGridColumn With £ Sign Instead of $ Sign

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting, culture

I have a `DataGridTextColumn` that stores a `Value`, I want the value to be displayed like `£123.456.789`. I have done this so far by doing;

`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C}"/>`

This however results in a column that looks like this;

[image]

Whilst I would rather the `,` be a `.` the main problem here is that I would like this to be a `£` not a `$`. How can I change the column so that it displays a pound sign instead of a dollar sign?

Comment: `£123.456.789` is it valid 
?

Comment: if you want the currency formatting to affect everything in your `Window` or `UserControl` then just add this `xml:lang="en-GB"` to your Window XAML like so: `<Window xml:lang="en-GB"/>`

Comment: @kyle, my bad, of course not, long day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ConverterCulture:

`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, ConverterCulture='en-GB', StringFormat=C}"/>`

Comment: This is almost perfect for me, the only issue is that I still have `123,456,789.00`. Do you know an easy fix for removing the `.00`?

Comment: You can hard code the pound symbol instead of using locale and currency. If you do this, then you can use formatting to remove the commas. `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, StringFormat=£0.00}"/>` If you want to keep the currency formatting, then you need to look into using a NumberFormatInfo variable and removing the comma separating.